# Magento 2: Errors displaying on setting devolper mode

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

On setting developer mode this error is displaying want to find the files which are causing this error what should I do remove this error.

> [2019-02-14 12:58:34] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout:
>   LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4e8c25a3874faeb17115e71caadc75f22 and handles
>   default, catalog_category_view, catalog_category_view_type_layered,
>   catalog_category_view_type_layered_without_children,
>   catalog_category_view_id_462: Please correct the XML data and try
>   again. Element 'arguments': Missing child element(s). Expected is (
>   argument ). Line: 852

Also this error

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException):
>   Element 'move': This element is not expected. Line: 64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error, you somewhere (in layout) used arguments without argument.

Ex.

```
<block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="compareProductLink" xsi:type="string">.action.tocompare</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

But you missed **<argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">** part.

Now you need to correct your xml and clear the cache.

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'move': This element is not expected.
Line: 64         and about this error ??